# Running a java program and using the return value in another program

Tags: java, elasticsearch, dependency-injection, logic, resthighlevelclient

So, what I need to do is create 2 RestHighLevelClients (for 2 different environments) in a Java ElasticSearch Connector. And then get data through the Clients from both environment.
Now, if I had the hostname and port number for both environment, there would have been no issues. I would have just created 2 clients and used them. But there's the problem, we don't know the hostname and port number and what happens is our program runs on the environment cluster (Testing, PROD) and get those environment variables from there (hostname, port no etc).

Therefore, if I run the program on the testing cluster, I only get the hostname and port no for the testing cluster, and If I run the program on the prod cluster, I can only create the rest client for prod cluster. I need both the clients for a single run.
So what i have thought of is creating 2 other java programs that will run separately on both testing and production, catch the hostname and port no from the clusters and forward them directly to my main program for the rest clients creation.

Is there a way to do this, i.e running both variable catcher programs and pasting the results in the main program and then running the main program. I'm pretty new to JAVA, so every help is appreciated.